# gets function in C does not read script perl or python by command line

Tags: c, function, scripting, gets

I need help! I made a program in C that reads with gets function, puts the contents into a buffer and print the buffer:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char buffer[100];
  gets(buffer);
  printf(buffer);
return 0;
}
```

But if I put a script in Perl or in python that prints four A, the gets function interprets it as a string and then print the string:
$(python -c "print 'A'*4")

Comment: I don't understand your question, please illustrate your problem a bit more. Also, `gets` has been removed from C (in C11) and was deprecated before that. Never use it, it's impossible to use safely.

Comment: The behaviour you describe is as expected.

Comment: Joachim Pileborg has already given me the solution in the answers, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* I know what you mean even though it's unclear (so I'm mostly guessing here): You want the output from the Perl or Python script to be input that is read by `gets` am I right? Then you need to *pipe* the output of the script into your program:

```
$ python -c "print 'A'*4" | ./your_program
```

This will pass the standard output from the `python` program through the pipe to the standard input of your program.

---

I also assume that this is for a class or exercise to learn about buffer overflows, because that's the only reason to use `gets` these days. It has been obsolete since the C99 standard, and in the C11 standard was removed completely.